# PHP: looping - how to add max items

Tags: php, instagram

I'm using the script below to display images from Instagram based on hashtag. It works perfectly, and lists all images avaliable by Instagram - up to 20 images.

However, I would like to be able to show less, say 10 or 12 images.

How can I add some sort of variable to hold a max item value so that the `foreach` loop doesn't loop all items??

PHP:

```
<?php
    // Enter hashtag;
    $hashtag = "nofilter";
    $url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/".$hashtag."/";
    $instagram_content = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match_all('/window._sharedData = (.*)\;\<\/script\>/', $instagram_content, $matches);
    $txt  = implode('', $matches[1]);
    $json = json_decode($txt);

    foreach ($json->entry_data->TagPage{0}->tag->media->nodes AS $item) {
        echo "<div class='imgbox'><a href='http://instagram.com/p/".$item->code."' target='_blank'><img class='hashtag' src='" . $item->display_src . "' alt=''></a></div>";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: "some sort of variable" like a counter?

Comment: Yes, like:
$noOfImages = 12;

- and then the foreach would loop through 12 images only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show 1-12 images and other not then use counter. in this code if counter is greater then 12 then loop will break so only 1-12 image will show

```
 $count = 0;
 foreach ($json->entry_data->TagPage{0}->tag->media->nodes AS $item) {
     if($count >= 12){
         break;
     }
     echo "<div class='imgbox'><a href='http://instagram.com/p/".$item->code."' target='_blank'><img class='hashtag' src='" . $item->display_src . "' alt=''></a></div>";
 $count++;     
 }
```

Comment: Exacly like this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Use a counter variable.

```
$loop_count = 0;
$max = 12;
foreach ($things as $thing) {
    if ($loop_count >= $max) {
        break;
    }

    // Do loop logic here

    $loop_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    $item = $json->entry_data->TagPage{0}->tag->media->nodes[$i];
    echo "<div class='imgbox'><a href='http://instagram.com/p/".$item->code."' target='_blank'><img class='hashtag' src='" . $item->display_src . "' alt=''></a></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If an array is number indexed then this work

```
foreach ( $list as $index => $value ) {
  if ( $index > 12 ) break;
  //do something
}
```

Implemented in your case is as the following:

```
<?php
    // Enter hashtag;
    $hashtag = "nofilter";
    $url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/".$hashtag."/";
    $instagram_content = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match_all('/window._sharedData = (.*)\;\<\/script\>/', $instagram_content, $matches);
    $txt  = implode('', $matches[1]);
    $json = json_decode($txt);

    foreach ($json->entry_data->TagPage{0}->tag->media->nodes AS $index => $item) {
        if ( $index > 12 ) break; 
        echo "<div class='imgbox'><a href='http://instagram.com/p/".$item->code."' target='_blank'><img class='hashtag' src='" . $item->display_src . "' alt=''></a></div>";
    }
  ?>
```